# Modal inside a carousel to stop the carousel from moving when modal is open

Tags: bootstrap-4, bootstrap-modal, carousel

Right now im trying to setup some sort of a testimonial widget.

Im having a carousel with a lot of text and a link to open a modal. When I open the modal I want the carousel to stop cycling for the course of the modal being open.

So far I have tried the `pause` and `interval` options from the bootstrap docs. As well as trying to stop the carousel by adding/changing the data-attribute `interval="false"`

live example:
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/QrYNQM

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-4">
    <!-- WIDGET  -->
    <aside class="card widget-card widget-feedback">
        <header class="card-header">
            <h4 class="h5 m-0 card-heading"><span class="text-primary">Deine</span> Meinung zählt</h4>
            <div class="carousel-controls">
                <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-slide="prev">
                    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                    <span class="sr-only">Vor</span>
                </a>
                <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-slide="next">
                    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                    <span class="sr-only">Zurück</span>
                </a>
            </div><!-- /.carousel-controls -->
        </header><!-- /.card-header -->
        <div class="card-body">
            <ul class="nav nav-pills" id="pills-tab" role="tablist">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link active" id="pills-feedback-latest-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#pills-feedback-latest" role="tab" aria-controls="pills-feedback-latest" aria-selected="true"><span class="fas fa-clock pr-2"></span>Neueste</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" id="pills-feedback-add-new-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#pills-feedback-add-new" role="tab" aria-controls="pills-feedback-add-new" aria-selected="false"><span class="fas fa-plus-circle pr-2"></span>Feedback abgeben</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <div class="tab-content" id="pills-tabContent">
                <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="pills-feedback-latest" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="pills-feedback-latest-tab">
                    <div id="carouselExampleControls" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
                        <div class="carousel-inner">

                            <div class="carousel-item active">
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-12">
                                        <div class="tm-h mb-0 p-2 hero">
                                            <p class="mb-0 pt-2 pr-2 pb-0 pl-2"><span class="fas fa-quote-left pr-2 text-primary"></span>
                                                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
                                                tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
                                                quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
                                                consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
                                                cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
                                                proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum <a class="open-modal-stop-carousel" href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#feedback-expanded-id">[...]</a><span class="fas fa-quote-right pl-2 text-primary"></span></p>                   


                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-12">
                                            <div class="tm-f p-2">
                                                <div class="row my-2 mx-1">
                                                    <div class="col-4 d-flex align-items-center">
                                                        <div class="">
                                                            <img src="http://placeimg.com/70/70/people" class="img-fluid -circle border border-default" alt="" />
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                    <div class="col-8">
                                                        <span><span class="fab fa-facebook pr-1"></span>Gabriella Luisa Wagner <small>vor 12 Tagen</small></span>

                                                        <ul class="mb-0 list-inline list-unstyled">
                                                            <li class="list-inline-item m-0" style="font-size: small">
                                                                <span class="fas fa-star pr-2"></span><span class="fas fa-star pr-2"></span><span class="fas fa-star pr-2"></span><span class="fas fa-star pr-2"></span><span class="fas fa-star-half pr-2"></span>
                                                            </li>

                                                        </ul>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="carousel-item">
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="col-12">
                                            <div class="tm-h mb-0 p-2 hero">
                                                <p class="mb-0 pt-2 pr-2 pb-0 pl-2"><span class="fas fa-quote-left pr-2 text-primary"></span>
                                                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
                                                    tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
                                                    quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
                                                    consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
                                                    cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
                                                    proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. <a class="open-modal-stop-carousel" href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#feedback-expanded-id">[...]</a><span class="fas fa-quote-right pl-2 text-primary"></span></p>                   


                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="col-12">
                                                <div class="tm-f p-2">
                                                    <div class="row my-2 mx-1">
                                                        <div class="col-4 d-flex align-items-center">
                                                            <div class="">
                                                                <img src="http://placeimg.com/70/70/people" class="img-fluid -circle border border-default" alt="" />
                                                            </div>
                                                        </div>
                                                        <div class="col-8">
                                                            <span><span class="fab fa-facebook pr-1"></span>Gabriella Luisa Wagner <small>vor 12 Tagen</small></span>

                                                            <ul class="mb-0 list-inline list-unstyled">
                                                                <li class="list-inline-item m-0" style="font-size: small">
                                                                    <span class="fas fa-star pr-2"></span><span class="fas fa-star pr-2"></span><span class="fas fa-star pr-2"></span><span class="fas fa-star pr-2"></span><span class="fas fa-star-half pr-2"></span>
                                                                </li>

                                                            </ul>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>


                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="tab-pane fade" id="pills-feedback-add-new" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="pills-feedback-add-new-tab">
                            <form>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Email address</label>
                                    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Enter email">
                                    <small id="emailHelp" class="form-text text-muted">We'll never share your email with anyone else.</small>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Password</label>
                                    <input type="password" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword1" placeholder="Password">
                                </div>
                                <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox my-1 mr-sm-2">
                                    <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="customControlInline">
                                    <label class="custom-control-label" for="customControlInline">Remember my preference</label>
                                </div>
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
                            </form>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div><!-- /. card-body -->
            </aside><!-- /. xxx -->
            <!-- END WIDGET  -->

            <!-- Modal -->
            <div class="modal fade" id="feedback-expanded-id" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                    <div class="modal-content">
                        <div class="modal-header">
                            <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Feedback von Gabriella Luisa Wagner</h5>
                            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                            </button>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-body">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-12">
                                    <div class="tm-h mb-0 p-2 hero">
                                        <p class="mb-0 pt-2 pr-2 pb-0 pl-2"><span class="fas fa-quote-left pr-2 text-primary"></span>
                                            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
                                            tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
                                            quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
                                            consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
                                            cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
                                            proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
                                            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
                                            tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
                                            quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
                                            consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
                                            cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
                                            proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.<span class="fas fa-quote-right pl-2 text-primary"></span></p>                   


                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-12">
                                        <div class="tm-f p-2">
                                            <div class="row my-2 mx-1">
                                                <div class="col-4 d-flex align-items-center">
                                                    <div class="">
                                                        <img src="http://placeimg.com/70/70/people" class="img-fluid -circle border border-default" alt="" />
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="col-8">
                                                    <span><span class="fab fa-facebook pr-1"></span>Gabriella Luisa Wagner <small class="d-block">vor 12 Tagen</small></span>

                                                    <ul class="mb-0 list-inline list-unstyled">
                                                        <li class="list-inline-item m-0" style="font-size: small">
                                                            <span class="fas fa-star pr-2"></span><span class="fas fa-star pr-2"></span><span class="fas fa-star pr-2"></span><span class="fas fa-star pr-2"></span><span class="fas fa-star-half pr-2"></span>
                                                        </li>

                                                    </ul>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="modal-footer">
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">schließen</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

JS attemp one

```
$(function () {

    $('.open-modal-stop-carousel').on('click', function(){
        $('#carouselExampleControls').data('interval', "false");
    });

});
```

JS attemp two

```
$(function () {

    $('.open-modal-stop-carousel').on('click', function(){
        $('#carouselExampleControls').carousel({
            pause: true,
            inverval: false
        });
    });

});
```

Neither of my attemps stopped the carousel from cycling. Im not sure what I am missing to stop it. A push in the right direction is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [modal events](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/modal/#events) **shown.bs.modal**, and **hidden.bs.modal**, and the [carousel methods](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/carousel/#methods) **pause** and **cycle**

Like this:

```
$(function () {

  $('#feedback-expanded-id').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
    $('#carouselExampleControls').carousel('pause');
  });

  $('#feedback-expanded-id').on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
    $('#carouselExampleControls').carousel('cycle');
  });

});
```